# Is there a secure way to declare a string variable in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, string

When working with PHP I always declared my string variable and set them equal to null just to be safe. I'm new to visual basic and am wondering what the safest way to declare a string variable is. Will

```
Dim strWords As String
```

be sufficient? Or is it better to set it to null or nothing or some other default value or primitive type?

Comment: Yes, from what I could tell. (But then I am a beginner, so take my advice with half a grain of salt worth two cents.)

Comment: @G That's a good question. I believe because I'm writing a simple console application that it's VB6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, strWords will be `Nothing` by default anyway.

Rather than ensuring this value is never nothing by setting a value when declaring the variable, you should ensure your code doesn't leave the possibility of `strWords` being Nothing, and if it is, dealing with it appropriately.

If you need to check whether a string is not empty or nothing, you can do:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWords) Then
```

Comment: So if I write: If strWords Then.... will that check if strWords does not equal nothing?

Comment: @Scott - no. Use `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWords) Then ... `

Comment: +1 Although since this is VB, you can check whether the string is not empty or nothing like this *If strWords <> "" Then*  The VB intrinsics treat Nothing as identical to ""

Answer (score 2):

The best way to declare a string variable is to set it to an empty string directly after declaration. It is a common mistake for most .NET developers to set a string to "" or Nothing. This is wrong because "" is not really an empty string for .NET CLR, and Nothing could throw a NullReferenceException if you reference the string later in the code. Below is the correct code for string declaration:

```
Dim str As String = "" ' <--This is "not best practice"
Dim str2 As String = Nothing ' <--This is "not best practice"
Dim str3 As String = vbNullString ' <--This is "not best practice"
Dim str4 As String = String.Empty ' <--correct
```

Comment: A string set to Nothing is less likely to cause a NullReferenceException in VB than C#. The VB intrinsics treat Nothing as identical to ""

Answer (score 0):

In .net and in VB.net, the best secure way to declare a string is give the variable a type name. For example:

```
Dim MyString As System.String
```

I like to declare a string (or any type) with fully qualified name to avoid confusion. And don't do this:

```
Dim MyString = "hello world"
```