# which is the best way to initialize a string with null in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, initialization

We can declare and initialize a `string` variable in `vb.net` in following ways:

```
 Dim str1 As String = ""
 Dim str2 As String = Nothing
 Dim str3 As String = vbNullString
```

**Question :**

- Which one is the best programming practice?
- What is the difference between these three methods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A string will be set to Nothing until you specify otherwise, so there is no need to initialise it like this:

```
Dim s As String = Nothing
```

because this is just the same as

```
Dim s As String
```

You may want to set it Nothing later on in your code but not at initialisation,

`vbNullString` is a carry over from VB6 days and is functionally equivalent to `Nothing`

A blank string (`""`) and `String.Empty` are equivalent.

---

Some say `String.Empty` has a slight performance advantage but I don't see any evidence.

Note: The IL produced by these two *is* different:

`""` produces:

```
IL_0001:  ldstr      ""
```

`String.Empty` produces:

```
IL_0001:  ldsfld     string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
```

---

So to answer your question:

```
Dim str1 As String = "" 'Initialises as blank string same as String.Empty
Dim str2 As String = Nothing 'Same as Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String = vbNullString 'Same as previous line but deprecated so avoid
```

So you should be using the following if you want an empty string

```
Dim s As String = ""
```

And the following if you want a Null (Nothing) string:

```
Dim s As String
```

Which one you want depends on what you are doing

Comment: Just for the record, I tested the `String.Empty vs ""` and I found out that `String.Empty` executes the code 5 clock ticks faster, so realy, the difference is **minor** and near to zero.

Comment: @Eminem - I bet if you ran it again the answer would be different. Running a test here there is no clear winner.

Answer (score 0):

All the three initializations you posted are functionally equivalent to an empty string or uninitialized string. None of them will be advantageous over the others. And even if it has, the advantage would be so small that it won't matter at all.

While individual views may differ, I feel initializing variables with empty/null value with declaration is a bad thing (in general), unless that variable's lifetime spans just a few lines. This is because it doesn't give the compiler any options for suggesting optimizations. Leaving things flexible for the compiler is particularly useful in big maintenance projects, where it is common to declare all variables at the top of the sub/function and use it later in the code.

Consider the following situation:

Two variables are declared at the top of a function and used somewhere in the code in the following way.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str1 As String = ""
    Dim str2 As String

    ' blah blah blah

    ' some code

    ' more code

    ' variables are used here
    str1 = "something"
    str2 = "something else"

End Sub
```

Now due to some maintenance requirements, the code where these variables were used is modified/removed and these variables are no longer needed. It is common to forget to remove the variable declarations in such situations. But if the declarations are not removed, the compiler would be able to warn for the `str2` variable, but not for `str1`.

[image]

For small functions this may not seem any good. But consider functions where the size spans in pages and everything doesn't fit on the screen. It is common for functions to grow in size in large maintenance projects. You get an advantage there.

While assigning empty/null value explicitly while declaring variables don't give you any special advantage, leaving it unassigned when declaring it gives you the advantage mentioned above.

Comment: The first paragraph here is incorrect `""` `<>` `Nothing`

Comment: That's why I said, they are functionally equivalent. `""` and `Nothing` are obviously different.

Comment: Clearly not obvious to the OP, hence the reason for the post in the first place. I just don't don't think it is very clear.

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim str As String = "" ' <--This is "not best practice"
Dim str2 As String = Nothing ' <--This is "not best practice"
Dim str3 As String = vbNullString ' <--This is "not best practice"
Dim str4 As String = String.Empty ' <--correct
```

By default, strWords will be Nothing by default anyway.

Rather than ensuring this value is never nothing by setting a value when declaring the variable, you should ensure your code doesn't leave the possibility of strWords being Nothing, and if it is, dealing with it appropriately.

If you need to check whether a string is not empty or nothing, you can do:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strWords) Then
```

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593288/is-there-a-secure-way-to-declare-a-string-variable-in-visual-basic)

Comment: Can you explain to the audience *why* the examples are not best practise?

Comment: i seem to remember reading that the IL for declaring strings as = "" and = String.Empty are identical

Comment: If `str4 will be Nothing by default` then why the warning is shown as "variable str2 is used before it has been assigned a value", when it is used without initialized

Comment: for the first three example. the instance of the creates an object of the string which has a value of nothing, string.empty is the safest because it does not create an object and has no value at all.

Comment: Your last comment is not correct. Setting it to blank string (`""`) is not the same as `Nothing`. And `String.Empty` *has* a value it is `""`

Comment: @5uperdan - actually they are not I just tested this but the difference is still negligable

Comment: @MattWilko I can see from your answer, thank you for correcting me :)